# iOS app no longer receiving push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, push

We had push notifications all nicely set up for our iOS app, but they stopped working a few weeks ago.

It looks like our requests are sent to `APNS` ok, but push notifications are not being received.

The only thing that has changed is:

1. Number of users in our database has grown to about `150`
2. The SSL certificate for our domain (not the `local_cert` that is sent to `APNS`) expired, but I don't think this would be the cause(?)

It all worked fine before, and everyone is still using the same version of the app.

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this or may be able to offer a suggestion?

Comment: I had this issue once, and it turned out the build submitted to the store had the development, not the deployment, info for our Urban Air account. If you are using Urban Air its pretty easy to see what UUIDs are currently reporting as active to them.

Comment: Cheers, David. We will look into this but I think the current build used to work then suddenly stopped working, so I presume it must be using the deployment info.

Comment: Apple will blacklist your app if you don't respond to the APNS returned list of devices to NOT send to.

Comment: I think that may well be the case. I only introduced code that code for the APNS feedback service recently - sounds like I was too late. Is there any way to get the app off the blacklist?

Comment: There is an email link on the Developer Admin page - you can try that. It usually takes a day or two for them to get back to you. I'd ask that they unlist my app, that there was a problem its now resolved.

Comment: Thanks, David. I'll post back if this indeed was the issue.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#techSupport

Comment: Apple have got back to me and sent me in this direction: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

My iOS7 developer application stopped receiving messages after changing Provisioning Profiles.

Try going into SETTINGS->NOTIFICATION CENTER, scroll down to your app, tap it and toggle your Alert style between NONE and the style you want.

As soon as I did that I got a notification. 
Maybe this might help someone save as many hours as I lost o_O